# With pandas: if, in a row, a word in a column does not occur in string in other column, drop row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say we have this dataframe:

```
from pandas import *

d = {'one' : Series(["word", "other-word", "banana", "hello"]),
    'two' : Series(["I like that word", "Have you seen other-word", "do you like bananas", "hello-kitty doll"])}

df = DataFrame(d)
```

How can I drop the rows in which `one` doesn't occur in `two`? For instance, on the third row `banana` doesn't match `bananas`: drop row. In the fourth: `hello` doesn't match `hello-kitty`: drop. That last one is important: compounds built with a hyphen `-` are obstacles.

Expected output:

```
          one                       two
0        word          I like that word
1  other-word  Have you seen other-word
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this:

```
result = []
for x, y in zip(df.one, df.two):
    if x in y.split():
        result.append(True)
        continue
    result.append(False)

print df[result]
```

A much better approach:

```
df[[ x in y.split() for x, y in zip(df.one, df.two) ]]
```

Comment: This works great and is faster than Anand's solution (I don't know why, but it is). A couple of questions to better understand the code: Why do we have to define `result` at the top as an empty list? How does Python know that result is par of `df` and not a solitary variable? And finally, why is the `result.append(False)` required?

Comment: Hi @BramVanroy , Q1. result is a list, before you append any element to it you have to declare a list instance of it. Q2.  python doesn't know that result is par of df. result is a list of booleans 'False' and 'True' when you pass it to df, it will only give you back the rows that match True and let go the others. Q3. As I mentioned previously, you need to have a list, in order for df to know which lines you don't want to keep, you have to specify which lines are not required (False).

Comment: If you print result you'll see: [True, True, False, False],  it tells df to give you the lines which are True, which means the first and the second and let go the rest.

Comment: I just edited the solution for a one line python code, have a look. You don't need result anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the code! I learn a lot from this!

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT** :

Another method would be to calculate the list of indexes to drop and store them in a list and then at the end use `DataFrame.drop()` . Example/Demo -

```
In [45]: dropseries = []

In [46]: for i, row in df.iterrows():
   ....:     if row['one'] not in row['two'].split():
   ....:         dropseries.append(i)
   ....:

In [47]: df.drop(dropseries)
Out[47]:
          one                       two
0        word          I like that word
1  other-word  Have you seen other-word
```

---

I am not sure if there is a better way to do this, but you can iterate over each row and then split the string in column `two` and then check if the string in column `one` exists in it or not, and then append the rows that match to a new dataframe .

Example -

```
newdf = pd.DataFrame()

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['one'] in row['two'].split():
        newdf = newdf.append(row)
```

---

Example/Demo -

```
In [38]: newdf = pd.DataFrame()

In [39]: for i, row in df.iterrows():
   ....:     if row['one'] in row['two'].split():
   ....:         newdf = newdf.append(row)
   ....:

In [40]: newdf
Out[40]:
          one                       two
0        word          I like that word
1  other-word  Have you seen other-word
```

Comment: YOBA's solution is faster. I don't know exactly why because it looks quite similar.

Comment: Because he does not create a new df every iteration. I have also added another method, which can be faster than my previous method

Comment: I like your second approach. It's equally as fast as YOBA's solution (in my small test).